# How can I markup in semantically correct way additional info in header? html5?

Tags: html

I'm struggling with semantics, while I enjoy thinking about meaning of the parts of the websites, it is becoming complicated...

Anyhow, if I've additional info box in the header (imagine tall header, with nav and h1 + additional text explaining what website is about and how it works). What will be logical/semantic element to contain it?

```
<figure id="info_how">
    <h2>Share what you will do for money, at the marketplace for small services!</h2>
    <p>bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. Duis sed amet <strong>nibh vulputate cursus</strong> sit.</p>

    <a id="button_start" href="#">Start selling</a>
    <a id="button_how" href="#">How does it work?</a>
</figure>
```

I'm thinking figure, but...

Comment: Why do you think of `figure` here? Could you give more markup of the context around this box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **[the specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element)**:

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document.
>
> The element can be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams, photos,
>   code listings, etc. This includes, but is not restricted to, content
>   referred to from the main part of the document, but that could,
>   without affecting the flow of the document, be moved away from that
>   primary content, e.g. to the side of the page, to dedicated pages, or
>   to an appendix.

So `figure` sounds good to me!

Additionally, I'd place a `<figcaption>` element inside of the `<h2>` tags:

```
<h2><figcaption>Share what you will do for money, at the marketplace for small services!</figcaption></h2>
```

Because it does represents the "caption" of the figure.

Comment: A `caption` is part of an HTML table and currently is not allowed in other tags. If you need a caption inside a `figure` you should use the appropriate `figcaption` tag. An `h2` is superfluous if this is the caption to the figure in whole. See also ["When a table element is the only content in a figure element other than the figcaption, the caption element should be omitted in favor of the figcaption."](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element)

Comment: @feeela: You're right, I got confused there :) Thanks for the fix.